# Normal subgroup involving quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $N$ be a normal subgroup of G.   Show that there
>   is a bijection between $N\times G/N$ and $G$.

I think I can define a map by $f : N\times G/N\to G$ where $(n,gN) \mapsto ng$.

Then $f$ is surjective. But how can I show that $f$ is injective? Or is it possible to find its inverse function?

> Let $G$ be a group, $N\triangleleft G$, and $G_{i}$, $G_{i+1}$ be two
>   subgroups of $G$ such that $G_{i}\triangleleft G_{i+1}$.
>   Then ($G_{i+1}\cap N$)/($G_{i}\cap N$) $\triangleleft$
>   $G_{i+1}$/$G_{i}$

I only know ($G_{i+1}\cap N$)/($G_{i}\cap N$) is well-defined. But I don't know what else I can do now.

Comment: For 1, you're multiplying on the wrong side.

Comment: What do you mean, gN? ng?

Comment: Is your map well defined?

Comment: Should be $gn$. Except that's not a well defined map. You have to single out a specific $g$ in each coset for it to work.

Comment: oops. I forgot to check.

Comment: The correspondence theorem says that there is a bijection between normal subgroups of $G/N$ and normal subgroups of $G$ containing $N$.

Comment: Ok, I edit the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prove the first statement. The proof of the second one is not short (but it's standard) and it needs to be asked in a separate question because it's irrelevant to the first statement.

From basic definitions in group theory, we know that the projection map $\pi: G \to G/N$ is well-defined and it's surjective. By the axiom of choice, it must have at least one right inverse. Take a right inverse of $\pi$ and call it $\phi: G/N \to G$. Therefore, $\pi \circ \phi=\mathbb{1}_{G/N}$. Note that $\phi$ has the property that it is constant on each equivalence class because of the way we constructed it. Now, define $f: N \times G/N \to G$ by

$$f(n,gN)=n\phi(gN)$$

By construction, $g_1N=g_2N$ gives that $\phi(g_1N)=\phi(g_2N)$. So, it's seen that $f$ is well-defined.

$f$ is also surjective because for any $g\in G$, there exists some $n_0 \in N$ such that $g\phi(gN)^{-1}=n_0$ because they belong to the same equivalence class. Hence, $g=f(n_0,gN)$.

To check injectivity, note that $f(n_1,g_1N)=f(n_2,g_2N)$ gives that

$$n_2^{-1}n_1=\phi(g_2N)\phi(g_1N)^{-1}$$
$$N=\pi(n_2^{-1}n_1)=\pi(\phi(g_2N)\phi(g_1N)^{-1})=\pi(\phi(g_2N))\pi(\phi(g_1N))^{-1}=(g_2N)(g_1^{-1}N)=g_2g_1^{-1}N$$

Hence, $g_2g_1^{-1}\in N$ and they belong to the same equivalence class. In other words, $\phi(g_1N) = \phi(g_2N)$. Hence, $n_1=n_2$ and $f$ is injective too.

Comment: $n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}$?   Not $n_{2}^{-1}n_{1}$ instead?

Comment: @Bill_Tsai Yes, you're right. I fixed it. Thanks.